# c# Find occurrences of string within a string and wrap text around the matching chars

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

Split string, example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q11k8Z)

```
 var hello = "Hello World";
```

I'm trying to get the result to be "Hello World"  with spans around the matching  "l"

```
    string[] words = hello.ToLower().Split("l");
    var resultString = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        // now we have split the string how do find the missing 'l' and wrap a span around them
        resultString += words[i].ToString();
    }
    // result is heo word
    Console.WriteLine(resultString);
    // Trying to get the result to be "He<span>l</span><span>l</span>o Wor<span>l<span>d
```

[see dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PsO6IU)

Comment: Console.WriteLine(hello.Replace("l", "<span>l</span>"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(hello, "l", x => $"<span>{x}</span>");
```

Comment: @fuzzybear, `string.Replace` suggested in comment is simpler, but regex can handle more complex match cases than a single letter

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("<span>l</span>", words));
```

Instead of

```
//No need to build resultString as well. That mean you can eliminate for loop
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

[.Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tx9NG8)

---

<sub>**Note:** This is just an alternate way aligned to your question. The solution proposed by @fuzzybear or @ASh are more elegant than what I suggested.</sub>

Comment: what if the 'l' is at the start or at the end of the string

Comment: @spzvtbg, I added fiddle, hope it will answer your question

Comment: you are right it works, because of the empty strings - i didn'tt see that at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Hello world";
string resulStr = str.Replace("l", "<span>l</span>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(resulStr);
```